# Are there any security related issues if we allow domain users to change their wallpaper and screen saver?

Tags: gpo

I know lots of company they lock users wallpaper and screen saver, but is there any risk to allow this?

Answer (score 1):

No, there are absolutely no security issues with changing a system's screensaver or wallpaper, at least if you are using the defaults. A company may enforce such a policy because they do not want people to display offensive or controversial material, or because they want to standardize a given look. Remember also that screensavers come from executable files, so there is a security reason to disallow people from downloading and *installing* arbitrary screensavers from the web.

Comment: Emphasis on the bit about installing arbitrary screensavers... and in a business environment, I think it's totally reasonable to lock the wallpaper and screensaver to something that represents the company well. If nothing else, a screensaver of the company logo reminds users who owns the computer.